# Trying to send an email with python

Tags: python, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257185/send-email-with-python)

I'm trying so send an email with python but when I run the script it take a minute or two then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./emailer", line 19, in <module>
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib

SERVER = 'addisonbean.com'

FROM = 'myemail@gmail.com'
TO = ['myemail@gmail.com']

SUBJECT = 'Hello!'

message = """\
Bla
Bla Bla 
Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla
"""

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

I also tried my site IP address as the server but that did the same thing.

Could someone tell me why it does this and how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the SMTP server require any authentication? Because they usually do

Comment: You need to use an actual mail server as the server address. You can't just put in any random hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the key bit:

```
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Python's saying: **I can't connect to that server, I've tried but it doesn't seem to respond**.

Here's the second key bit:

```
SERVER = 'addisonbean.com'
```

That's not a mail server, is it?

Comment: It's not. I don't really know what a mail server is...

Comment: It's very difficult to send an e-mail without knowing what a mail server is, unfortunately. You'd think this stuff would be easy as pie by today, but it's not quite there yet. You should start by learning about e-mail!

Answer (score 1):

While `addisonbean.com` does listen 25 port and answers `220 accra.dreamhost.com ESMTP` - you seems to be behind proxy or some kind of firewall. Can you do `telnet addisonbean.com 25` from your console?

Comment: No. It says this addisonbean: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: Nope. It says this: Trying 69.163.221.133...
telnet: connect to address 69.163.221.133: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: So - you know your reason. This is network-related problem, not of your application.

Comment: @Victor Gavro: Dang!! I saw this conversation right after I spent 20 minutes preparing my answer... **:D :D** What a waste... Good luck, btw (for @user1525759)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hosting your page in [dreamhost.com](http://dreamhost.com), a hosting provider.

When you set up your account, they probably gave you the chance to create email accounts ending with your domain (*yaddayadda@addisonbean.com*)

You may want to create one, get the information: host where the SMTP (the "mail server") is located, username, password... And you'll have to fill all that in your script.

I would recommend you start testing with another regular account (Gmail.com, <strike>Hotmail</strike> Outlook.com) and that you read (quite a bit) about what an SMTP server is (which is the server you'll have to talk to in order to have your email sent)

Here's a simple script that should send emails using a gmail account. Fill the information that is shown with asterisks with your data, see if it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import traceback
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpPort = 587
smtpUsername = "***@gmail.com"
smtpPassword = "***"
sender = "***@gmail.com"

def sendEmail(to, subject, content):
    retval = 1
    if not(hasattr(to, "__iter__")):
        to = [to]
    destination = to

    text_subtype = 'plain'
    try:
        msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all

        conn = SMTP(host=smtpHost, port=smtpPort)
        conn.set_debuglevel(True)
        #conn.login(smtpUsername, smtpPassword)
        try:
            if smtpUsername is not False:
                conn.ehlo()
                if smtpPort != 25:
                    conn.starttls()
                    conn.ehlo()
                if smtpUsername and smtpPassword:
                    conn.login(smtpUsername, smtpPassword)
                else:
                    print("::sendEmail > Skipping authentication information because smtpUsername: %s, smtpPassword: %s" % (smtpUsername, smtpPassword))
            conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
            retval = 0
        except Exception, e:
            print("::sendEmail > Got %s %s. Showing traceback:\n%s" % (type(e), e, traceback.format_exc()))
            retval = 1
        finally:
            conn.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print("::sendEmail > Got %s %s. Showing traceback:\n%s" % (type(e), e, traceback.format_exc()))
        retval = 1
    return retval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sendEmail("***@gmail.com", "Subject: Test", "This is a simple test")
```

Once you have the equivalent information for your domain (*smtpHost, smtpPort, smtpUsername...*) it MAY work as well (depends on the port they're using, it may be 25, which is the default for non-encrypted connections... or not... You'll have to check with *dreamhost.com* for that)

Be aware that (since you're using a hosting that probably shares its SMTP server with other people) your "sender" may be *yaddayadda@addisonbean.com* but the actual information to connect to the *dreamhost.com* SMTP servers may be different: I'm guessing the '`smtpUsername`' may be the username you use to login in your site admin, the '`smtpHost`' may change to something like `smtp.dreamhost.com` or such... That I don't really know.

You have a [lot of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20smtplib%20example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs) on how to do that.

You also seem to be a designer or photographer... One of those <strike>dudes</strike> people concern on how things look on the screen and all... Then you may wanna investigate what [MiME emails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) are. You know... so the email is not sent with text only, but you can put fancy HTML in it... *You know what I'm sayin'?*