# Query SQL for record then send email if none exists

Tags: sql, windows, email, sql-server-2012, scheduled-tasks

I've been tasked to write an application that will test whether our morning checks have been submitted to our database. If not the app should email us. It needs to query the database (SQL Server 2012) for an entry with today's date.

The database is a very small table with 8 columns in it: `ID`, `Username(varchar)`, `DateTime(DateTime)`, and then some more varChar fields for comments.

I have not done this before so I'm assuming that I'll have to use a Windows scheduled task? Does anyone know what language I should write it in?

Comment: Hey what database are you using? There are probably *many* programming languages that can be used to query your database.

Comment: SQL -  2012, It only has to be a simple app.

Comment: Stack Overflow [encourages questions that are specific](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It sounds like you may want to break your project into several steps: e.g. 1. How to query the database for an entry with today's date (sharing part of your database schema would be helpful); 2. What scripting language can run the query from part 1, parse the results and send an email; 3. How to run this script repeatedly every day (this will depend on your OS, your source control setup, etc.). Please try to be a bit more specific and do some research so we can help you :)

Comment: Do you mean [Microsoft SQL Server 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions.aspx)?

Comment: Yes Microsoft 2012 - I want to be use windows scheduled task to run some sort of script that checks the DB for an entry with todays date on. If it doesn't find it then email an email address.

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know what the database tables look like? Are you able to share part of the schema that stores "entries with the date"? Keep in mind you can choose a different name for the tables and columns here to keep the actual schema details private if you like.

Comment: I have edited your question to note you're using sql-server 2012, but please provide some database details if you can do so.

Comment: The db is a very small table with 8 columns in it. ID,Username(varchar), DateTime(DateTime), and then some more varChar fields for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow [encourages questions that are specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It sounds like you may want to break your project into several steps:

**1. How to query the database for an entry with today's date?**

In SQL Server 2012 try something like this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM table T
WHERE DateTime = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

You can check to see if the query returned any data.

**2. What scripting language can run the query from part 1, parse the results and send an email?**

I'm going to suggest [python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) - it's easy to set up, clean to work with, and fun to use. Stack Overflow has [many questions and answers about python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), or feel free to ask another question if you can't find the answer already.

[Here is an answer on how to send emails from a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11257349/28037). Yuu can also read [the python docs on sending email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html).

**3. How to run this script repeatedly every day?**

One option is to create a Windows Scheduled Task. [Here is an answer from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/403597/247195), Stack Overflow's sister site that deals with using hardware and software.

**4. What about my next question?**

For the future I'd suggest searching this site, using a search engine, and breaking your problems down into individual parts. Good luck!